# C# Outlook Addin Not Installing Correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, outlook, add-in, outlook-2013

I am currently having issues when deploying my Outlook Addin. When I sent the Addin off to QA these are the only 2 issues that she found. I have browsed the intranet for hours now and cannot find a solution to my 2 issues.

Some details first:

- I am using Visual Studio 2012
- I am making a Outlook 2013 Addin
- The addin works fine apart from these 2 issues
- I am using the default clickonce installer

My First issue is that when I install my addin the location in the Outlook Options is pointing to the vsto file and not the .Dll file. I need it to install to the default outlook directry and reference the .dll and not the vsto file.

My second issue is that even though I have filled out every "Publish" field in Visual Studio it still says Publish  in the Outlook Options window. I did find out that this could have something to do with my signed certificate.

I have no idea how to fix these two issues and instead of wasting more time searching I thought I could ask for some help.

Here is a picture that shows my 2 issues when Installed on my PC (Dev PC):

[image: Image of the Outlook Option screen with my 2 issues]

Here is a picture that shows my 2 issues when Installed on somebody elses PC:

[image]

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue 1 is normal for the basic Outlook-Addin project. For it to reference the dll in the location field you will need to create a raw addin.

You will need to remove the VSTO layer from the project then you will need to expose and register your own _IDTExtensbility2 interface implementation. Here is a start to give you an idea of what route you need to take: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.idtextensibility2(v=vs.90).aspx

Issue 2 I believe you are correct it does have something to do with the signed certificate. When you buy or create a valid Certificate it will include your Publisher inside it, it should then display in the options window.

I hope I have helped a little and set your on the right track :)

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at it now. If you have indeed set me on the right track I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks this does seem like the right route to take but it takes too much time and effort for what its worth so we have decided to leave it. However you are still correct and I have accepted your answer. Thanks mate.